# Text view height and width is not changing?

Tags: android, typeface

I am adding text view dynamically on an absolute layout. Below is the code for absoulute layout. Its working. But problem is when I am increasing the size of text of text view. Then width and height of text view is not changing. Someone please help.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int count = getChildCount();

    int maxHeight = 0;
    int maxWidth = 0;

    // Find out how big everyone wants to be
    measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    // Find rightmost and bottom-most child
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            int childRight;
            int childBottom;

            LayoutParams lp
                    = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            childRight = lp.x + child.getWidth();
            childBottom = lp.y + child.getHeight();

            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, childRight);
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, childBottom);
        }
    }

    // Account for padding too
    maxWidth += getPaddingLeft () + getPaddingRight ();
    maxHeight += getPaddingTop () + getPaddingBottom ();
    /* original
    maxWidth += mPaddingLeft + mPaddingRight;
    maxHeight += mPaddingTop + mPaddingBottom;
    */

    // Check against minimum height and width
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, getSuggestedMinimumWidth());

    setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

Comment: just check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940765/why-setting-text-from-onmeasure-does-not-affect-textview

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `getWidth` and `getHeight`, you should use `getMeasuredWidth` and `getMeasuredHeight` after measuring a child

Comment: it was getMeasuredWidth and Height.it was not working. so that is not a issue

Answer (score 0):

you can just adjust this at layout ( .xml )

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You can make it like "100dp" etc.