# why do'nt super.onMeasure or textView,setText() trigger measure pass again?

Tags: android, user-interface, invalidation, measure, onmeasure

I have some android code of a custom FrameLayout. The code changes some textView text.

I see the change take effect only when i call `super.onMeasure(...,...)`

I would expect it to call `onMeasure()` automatically when the text change via code or when I call `view.invalidate()`

why is the later not effecting the UI?

```
 @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (myAccountView.getVisibility() == GONE) {
      return;
    }
 //some more code
    for (int i = 0; i < chipTexts.size(); i++) {
      String text = chipTexts.get(i);
      myAccountView.setText(text);
      if (myAccountView.getPaint().measureText(text) <= textMaxWidth) {
        break;
      }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
```

is calling `super.onMeasure()` at the end more efficient than calling `view.requestLayout()`?

Comment: Please add your relevant code to the question. Also you might want to check if the call to invalidate is made on the UI thread.

Comment: [Why setting text from onMeasure does not affect TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940765/why-setting-text-from-onmeasure-does-not-affect-textview)

Comment: @Trenton_M thanks for the link, but it doesn't really explain why text change doesn't trigger the layoutpass automatically.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk 
is calling `super.onMeasure()` at the end more efficient than calling `view.requestLayout()`?

Comment: When you're implementing the method onMeasure you're actually supposed to call `super.onMeasure()` with your own measured values. Calling `invalidate` won't change anything if you don't actually pass the measurements to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [requestLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestLayout()) for your view. [invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#invalidate()) means that onDraw will be called for your view. But if your view changes its bounds you have to call requestLayout.

Comment: thank you, but why doesn't text change trigger the layoutpass automatically?

Comment: in addition, why does my extra call to super.onMeasure() have the same effect as calling `requestLayout()`?

Comment: is calling `super.onMeasure()` at the end more efficient than calling `view.requestLayout()`?

Comment: Well, if you TextView will trigger layout pass every time when updated I think you can imagine what will be with FPS. But  you can check the source code of the TextView and make sure that TextView trigger everything as well (just try to search "checkForResize" and "checkForRelayout") .

Comment: About why `requestLayout()` is better than `onMeasure()`, you have to figure out that `measure` pass from the Parent to Childs, because the Parent should know about Children's size to place it correct inside of itself. And `requestLayout()` just mark your view and ALL it's parents like `dirty`. It means in next `render pass` view hierarchy will be updated correctly.

Comment: but when i call onMeasure, i'm still in the measure pass. so it's actually cheaper than doing the whole pass again in the future. no?